# Invert a (small) permutation

Tags: bit-manipulation, opencl, intrinsics

I'm using the shuffle function of OpenCL to sort a float3 vector, like this (the last component of the actual 4d vector is ignored):

```
uint4 mask = (uint4)(0,1,2,3);
mask.xyz = res.x < res.y ? (res.x >= res.z ? mask.yxz : mask.yzx) : (res.y >= res.z ? mask.xyz : mask.xzy);
float4 abcd = shuffle(res,mask);
```

I then manipulate each component of the vector `abcd`, and want to reverse the sorting permutation, as follows:

```
uint4 inv_mask = ... // ???
res = shuffle(abcd,inv_mask); // Inverse the sorting permutation
```

How do I calculate the inverse mask efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of possibilities is very limited:

1. x >= y >= z    =>   mask.xyz = (0,1,2), inv_mask = (0,1,2)
2. x >= z >= y    =>   mask.xyz = (0,2,1), inv_mask = (0,2,1)
3. y >= x >= z    =>   mask.xyz = (1,0,2), inv_mask = (1,0,2)
4. y >= z >= x    =>   mask.xyz = (1,2,0), inv_mask = (2,0,1)
5. z >= x >= y    =>   mask.xyz = (2,0,1), inv_mask = (1,2,0)
6. z >= y >= x    =>   mask.xyz = (2,1,0), inv_mask = (2,1,0)

Notice that only two of the six possible permutation contains more than one swap, and thus the rest 4 permutations are inverted by themselves.

Once you have computed `mask`, you can use the following code to get `inv_mask`:

`inv_mask.xyz = mask.xyz == (int3)(1,2,0) ? (int3)(2,0,1) : (mask.xyz == (int3)(2,0,1) ? (int3)(1,2,0) : mask.xyz);`

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean
    `uint4 invmask = (uint4)(3,3,3,3) - mask;`
?

For a mask (0,3,1,2) this gives you (3-0, 3-3, 3-1, 3-2) = (3,0,2,1)

Comment: No, this does not give the inverse permutation (e.g. the inverse of the identity permutation mask, 0,1,2,3, should not be changed).

Comment: This sounds like that you have a permutation matrix (consisting of 1 at (i,j) if element i is placed at position j, 0 otherwise) and your inverted permutation should be the inverted matrix.

Comment: Right. But inverting the matrix is too expansive.

Comment: I would totally agree. Another option could be to precalculate the 24 (?) permutations beforehand (on the CPU) and transfer them as constant, global float array. From the memory viewpoint this is no big overhead.